# Google Cloud with Gradle cache

Tags: gradle, google-cloud-platform

Let's say I have a step:

```
steps:
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gradle'
      args: ['build']
```

and then do something with built app.
Are there any ways to leave the gradle's cache for the future builds? Currently, it keeps downloading all dependencies each time.

According to docs, I can use for example **volumes** option, eg:

```
volumes:
    - name: 'vol1'
      path: '/persistent_volume'
```

and subsequent steps will have an access to that mounted folder. But seems like it clears between new runs.

Answer (score 0):

The cloudbuild create a workplace for the builds. You can keep the same workplace volume for your all steps by the same volume in each step.

Below is an example:

```
    steps:
  # Get the saved global gradle cache from
  # Google Cloud Storage if it exists.
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
    entrypoint: 'sh'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        # Global
        if gsutil -q stat gs://${PROJECT_ID}_cloudbuild/gradle_global.tar.gz; then
          cd /
          gsutil cp gs://${PROJECT_ID}_cloudbuild/gradle_global.tar.gz gradle_global.tar.gz
          tar -xpzf gradle_global.tar.gz
        fi
    volumes:
      - name: 'gradle_global'
        path: /root/.gradle

  # Build the java package.
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gradle'
    entrypoint: 'sh'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        # Build the gateway .war package.
        ./gradlew -Pprod -DskipTests clean bootRepackage

        # Move the files needed for the docker image
        # to the slim directory.
        mv ./build/libs/*.war ./app.war

        # Delete all files and folders in the current directory
        # except for the `app.war` and `Dockerfile`.
        find . -type d -exec rm -rf {}
        find . -type f -not -name 'app.war' -not -name 'Dockerfile' -delete
    volumes:
     - name: 'gradle_global'
       path: /root/.gradle

  # Save the global gradle cache to Google Cloud Storage
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
    entrypoint: 'sh'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        # Global
        echo 'Creating an archive of /root/.gradle directory'
        tar -cpzf gradle_global.tar.gz /root/.gradle/
        echo 'Saving archive to Cloud Storage'
        gsutil cp gradle_global.tar.gz gs://${PROJECT_ID}_cloudbuild/gradle_global.tar.gz
        # Cleaning up
        echo 'Deleting gradle*.tar.gz'
        rm -f gradle*.tar.gz
  volumes:
    - name: 'gradle_global'
      path: /root/.gradle

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['pull', 'asia.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/${IMAGE_NAME}:latest']

  # Build the gateway container image.
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
      - 'build'
      - '-t'
      - 'asia.gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${COMMIT_SHA}'
      - '-t'
      - 'asia.gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${IMAGE_NAME}:latest'
      - '--cache-from'
      - 'asia.gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${IMAGE_NAME}:latest'
      - '.'

images:
  - asia.gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/gateway:${COMMIT_SHA}
  - asia.gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/gateway:latest
```